# Epson Tm-T88v print issue

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, epson-workforce

Why does print job get into queue when I use port monitor on the printer port for an EPSON TMT88V receipt printer?

I have installed EPSON standard Windows driver with printer installed on the physical serial port. I installed port monitor to monitor data on serial port.

After restarting the system when I send a print job it stays in print queue. When I stop the port monitor and print to printer and then start the port monitor it prints properly. I am unable to understand why TM-T88V waits for sample print without port monitor?

It's related to Windows driver programming. Port monitor  mentioned in the question is Windows driver created by me.

How can I add minimal reproducible example for Windows driver code? I can't post the code due to company policies.

I just need understanding of why this is happening

Comment: Tough Question. So you have written a _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Device Driver that is not really working correctly. You are not allowed to post the Source Lines of Code that might be erroneous. And _still_ you want us to perform some kind of Imaginary Debug Process. Very Difficult Situation.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.  If a minimal reproducible code example was provided I would have voted to migrate this to Stack Overflow.  However, without an example, I know it would be closed.